# Invalid Syntax code

Tags: python

# Set the background color
        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.AMAZON)

```
    # Set the viewport boundaries
    # These numbers set where we have 'scrolled' to.
    self.view_left = 0
    self.view_bottom = 0
    **print(f"Total wall blocks: {len(self.wall_list)}")**

def on_draw(self):
    """
    Render the screen.
    """
```

**Invalid Syntax** keeps coming up when the code is run in it's entirety. I am usually quite good at fixing problems in Python code for my students but this is stumping me. We use Python 3.4.4

Comment: **print line is not correct python syntax.  Also, there doesn't seem to be any code in your on_draw function.  That would also throw a syntax error.  Also, above your on_draw function you have some random indented code.  Basically there is almost no valid syntax in your above code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `f` string syntax is only available in Python 3.6. Try

```
print("Total wall blocks: {}".format(len(self.wall_list)))
```

PS I'm assuming that you're using the `**` around your `print` for emphasis. If not, remove them as well